# Sync two ViewPagers inside a Vertical ViewPager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have an `activity`. Inside that `activity` I have implemented [`VerticalViewPager`](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager) in which 3 pages are fed i.e. `Upper Page`, `Middle page` and `Lower Page`. Inside the middle page fragment and Lower page fragment I have separately another `ViewPagers(Horizontal)`.Inside these `ViewPagers` I have 3/3 pages each. So far I have been able to make them working just fine i.e. on vertical swipe gesture the `VerticalViewPager` gets triggered and on horizontal swipe gesture native android `ViewPager` gets triggered. Now I need to sync the horizontal swipe transition between the middle fragment pages and lower fragment pages.

Let me give an example: say I have A,B and C pages inside middle fragment of `VerticalViewPager` and D,E,F inside the lower vertical fragment. Assume I am in the middle fragment now. So when I swipe from A to B left to right, the lower fragment should also swipe from D to E automatically.

> [P.S.: For the horizontal(native) `ViewPager` to work inside
>   `VerticalViewPager`, the horizontal `ViewPager` Adapter needs to run
>   in the `AsyncTask` or `thread`s. So please consider this scenario as
>   well]

Answer (score 0):

You can make the adapter scope available globally and set the current view or fragment according to the change in the middle fragment.

According to the example:

[image]

Comment: Hi amalBit. Thanks for the answer but will viewPager3.setCurrentItem(position); cause the sliding animation that occurs naturally when viewPager2.OnPageChangeListener() is triggered? I neeed the sliding transition effect in VerticalViewPager 3 just like in VerticalViewPager 2.